# Layout of markdown table is off when using specific math symbols in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

The following markdown

```
| Symbol | Description |
| - | - |
| $FOO^{\text{bar}} $ | foo |
```

renders as follows

[image: poorly rendered table]

Whereas, the following code

```
| Symbol | Description |
| - | - |
| $F^{\text{bar}} $ | foo |
```

renders nicely

[image: nicely rendered table]

What might be causing this?